# Angularjs error when i try remove button and append a new?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have follow.js:

```
'user strict';

var SaurioApp = angular.module('SaurioApp', []);

SaurioApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.followUser = function(user_id,follow_to_id){
        $http.get('ajax/follow', {
            params: {user_id: user_id,follow_to_id: follow_to_id}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.unfollow = '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-  click="followUser({{Auth::user()->id}},{{$user->id}})">Seguir</button>';
        });
    }

});
```

and the view in blade

```
<div class="row" ng-app="SaurioApp">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
        <p ng-controller="SearchCtrl" >
            @{{ unfollow }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="followUser({{Auth::user()->id}},{{$user->id}})">Follow</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The insert is successful, but I can't delete the "Follow" button and append the new one: "Unfollow." How can I make this work?

Comment: If you add html dynamically you would need to $compile. It will be easier to take the button to your html and do ngShow on after insert is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row" ng-app="SaurioApp">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
        <p ng-controller="SearchCtrl" >
            <button ng-show='unfollow' class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="followUser({{Auth::user()->id}},{{$user->id}})">Seguir</button>
            <button ng-hide='unfollow' class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="followUser({{Auth::user()->id}},{{$user->id}})">Follow</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Similar to what @redoc says but with two buttons, one for unfollow and one for follow

```
SaurioApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.followUser = function(user_id,follow_to_id){
        $http.get('ajax/follow', {
            params: {user_id: user_id,follow_to_id: follow_to_id}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.unfollow = true;
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: True, but I have found in some causes that with the hide/show sometimes both show up for a split second.  I think that the DRY principle may apply here as well as the class and button text is really all that needs to be changed.  Less code.

Comment: Does this happen even when you use the same variable for hide/show like: ng-show='unfollow' and ng-hide='unfollow'. I have update the code

Comment: Yes, in some cases I have found a slight delay between the time when the code loads and the ng-hide/ng-show logic fires.   Either way, it can be done with less code which in the end (in my opinion) is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the only changes needed to be made are the CSS class and button text so in this case instead of trying to send HTMl code through the scope just send a variable and use ng-class to make the switch.  Something like this:

'user strict';

```
var SaurioApp = angular.module('SaurioApp', []);

SaurioApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.followUser = function(user_id,follow_to_id){
$scope.unfollow=false;
        $http.get('ajax/follow', {
            params: {user_id: user_id,follow_to_id: follow_to_id}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.unfollow = true;
        });
    }

});

<div class="row" ng-app="SaurioApp">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
        <p ng-controller="SearchCtrl" >
            @{{ unfollow }}
            <button ng-class="{btn-danger: unfollow=false }" ng-click="followUser({{Auth::user()->id}},{{$user->id}})">Follow</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also change the button text dynamically with something like this:

```
 <button value="{{(unfollow=false)? 'Follow' : 'Seguir'}}" ng-class="{btn-danger: unfollow=false }" ng-click="followUser({{Auth::user()->id}},{{$user->id}})"></button>
```

I guess the point being there is no need to actually recreate the HTML code just change the elements.